# Install second wordpress in root subfolder, Error 404

Tags: htaccess, directory, installation

I am trying to install wordpress in a subfolder of an existing wordpress installation. I created a the subfolder `/wp` unziped a fresh Wordpress download inside of that directory and added a `.htaccess` with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
```

However if I visit `mysite.com/wp` I get an error 404 not found. I already tried the following: Restarting Apache and adding the `.htaccess` content to the root `.htaccess`. But it did not help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `/wp` subdirectory is included in the WordPress config? What happens when you request `example.com/wp/` (with a trailing slash)? I would expect no difference, however, if you omit the trailing slash then you are relying on mod_dir issuing a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash (which is dependent on the `DirectorySlash` directive). And what if you request `example.com/wp/index.php` directly? Again that avoids mod_dir having to issue an internal subrequest to the `DirectoryIndex`. So it's really just ruling our server config issues.

Comment: @MrWhite I tried `example.com/wp/index.php` but I am still redirected to the theme default error 404 page. Also the request in the network tab is showing me error 404 in the header.

Comment: @MrWhite And what do you mean by "confirmed that the /wp subdirectory is included in the WordPress config"? Adding a trailing slash doesn't provide me any difference in the result.

Comment: Under WordPress "General Settings", the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" should both include the `/wp` subdirectory.

Comment: @MrWhite I cant check that because Wordpress is not installed yet. Or do you mean the root installation? I tried to add 
`define('WP_HOME','http://new.spirigarchitektur.ch/wp');` and `define('WP_SITEURL','http://new.spirigarchitektur.ch/wp');`. But it did not help.

Comment: "Wordpress is not installed yet"?! Why did you manually create the `.htaccess` file? Have you tried running `install.php`?

Comment: @MrWhite Because I cannot run `install.php` due to the error 404. I have deleted the `.htaccess` and tried to open `mysite.com/wp/install.php` but I still get the error 404.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with Apache for quite a while, so this is untested.
RewriteBase is the *base* for your rewrite, so it's added to your rule automatically and your `.htaccess` should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Look here for further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Also, you probably want to only put that in the `.htaccess` file inside your `/wp` directory.

Comment: There's actually no real difference between these directives and the OP's directives in the question. With the OP's directives the `RewriteBase` directive is redundant since the `/wp` subdirectory is _hardcoded_ in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_. With your directives it will rewrite to `/wp/index.php` (making use of `RewriteBase`) - the net result is the same. In fact, in your code, the `RewriteBase` directive could be removed entirely (when the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/wp` subdirectory).

Comment: If the `.htaccess` is in the subdirectory, the RewriteBase does not make much sense, right.
If it's in the root directory, the OP's directive would lead to rewrites that duplicate the `/wp` which will not work. For instance `/wp/some-page` would be rewritten to `/wp/wp/some-page`

Comment: "If the .htaccess is in the subdirectory, the RewriteBase does not make much sense, right." - it does make sense, it's just that it's not necessarily required here. "`/wp/some-page` would be rewritten to `/wp/wp/some-page`" - not with the OP's directives. The `RewriteBase` only applies to relative path _substitutions_ (ie. paths that do not start with a protocol or a slash). In the OP's case the `RewriteBase` directive is effectively ignored since the _substitution_ string (`/wp/index.php`) is not considered "relative".

Comment: However, it transpires from comments above, that WordPress isn't actually installed yet. So, I'm not sure what is going on?

Comment: In that case - mea culpa. I should think more before writing ...